# removing the last repeated lines in the text files

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file as follows;

```
ALIC00AUS_R_20183350000.gz -4052052.7 4212835.9 -2545104.6
ALIC00AUS_R_20183350000.gz -4052052.7 4212836.0 -2545104.6
ALIC00AUS_R_20183350000.gz -4052052.7 4212836.0 -2545104.6
ALIC00AUS_R_20183350000.gz -4052052.7 4212835.9 -2545104.6
ALIC00AUS_R_20183350000.gz -4052052.5 4212836.0 -2545104.6
ALIC00AUS_R_20183350000.gz -4052052.6 4212835.9 -2545104.6
CPVG00CPV_R_20183460000.gz 5626883.4 -2380932.3 1824483.9
CPVG00CPV_R_20183460000.gz 5626883.4 -2380932.3 1824483.9
CPVG00CPV_R_20183460000.gz 5626883.3 -2380932.2 1824483.1
```

In this file, `ALIC00AUS_R_20183350000.gz` and `CPVG00CPV_R_20183460000.gz`  repeat six and three times, respectively. I need to remove the last repeated lines of each string in column 1 and the output should be as follows;

```
ALIC00AUS_R_20183350000.gz -4052052.7 4212835.9 -2545104.6
ALIC00AUS_R_20183350000.gz -4052052.7 4212836.0 -2545104.6
ALIC00AUS_R_20183350000.gz -4052052.7 4212836.0 -2545104.6
ALIC00AUS_R_20183350000.gz -4052052.7 4212835.9 -2545104.6
ALIC00AUS_R_20183350000.gz -4052052.5 4212836.0 -2545104.6
CPVG00CPV_R_20183460000.gz 5626883.4 -2380932.3 1824483.9
CPVG00CPV_R_20183460000.gz 5626883.4 -2380932.3 1824483.9
```

Comment: Your question has some issues:  The line "ALIC00AUS_R_20183350000.gz" repeats only 4 times in your example, then switches to  "ALIC00AUS_R_20183370000.gz".  Within the section that is "LIC00AUS_R_20183350000.gz" there are two identical sets of strings.  Are you looking for only unique strings?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for  only unique strings. I edited the question.

Comment: Thanks!  It seems wither of the answers mentioned by @RaidPinata below, will work for you.  If the file is large, you may want to look more deeply into the lines referenced from stack exchange, and use the `sort` command rather than `awk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are *sure* that each `$1` (first column) is duplicated at least once, then you can:

1. reverse the order of lines
2. only select those lines whose `$1` **has** been seen before
3. reverse the result

Ex.

```
$ tac file | awk 'seen[$1]++' | tac
ALIC00AUS_R_20183350000.gz -4052052.7 4212835.9 -2545104.6
ALIC00AUS_R_20183350000.gz -4052052.7 4212836.0 -2545104.6
ALIC00AUS_R_20183350000.gz -4052052.7 4212836.0 -2545104.6
ALIC00AUS_R_20183350000.gz -4052052.7 4212835.9 -2545104.6
ALIC00AUS_R_20183350000.gz -4052052.5 4212836.0 -2545104.6
CPVG00CPV_R_20183460000.gz 5626883.4 -2380932.3 1824483.9
CPVG00CPV_R_20183460000.gz 5626883.4 -2380932.3 1824483.9
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can meet the guarantee in the answer provided by @steeldriver that is the better solution, if not use this script.

```
##!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
  if (!seen[$1]++) {
    line = $0
    prev = $1
  }
  else {
    if (prev == $1) print line
    line = $0
  }
}
END { if (prev != $1) print line }
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk is a go to program for doing this kind of replacemen.

To remove lines that have a duplicate in the first column this should do it.

`awk '!seen[$1]++' filename > outputfile`

If you need to remove full duplication of lines use this instead.

`awk '!seen[$0]++' filename > outputfile`

As seen in this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171091/remove-lines-based-on-duplicates-within-one-column-without-sort

Here is a brief explanation. awk is used for pattern scanning and text processing. First, it checks if the value in column 1 ($1) is in the map seen. If it isn't it prints the line to the output file, or screen if you don't redirect (> outputfile). The next part is that it adds the viewed column info to seen (++) so it can search with the next pattern.

Comment: @RaidPinata, this doesn't solve the problem. The above code removes all the repeated lines except for the first one.

Comment: @deepblue_86 when I ran this with a test file it removed the duplicates as requested. Do you need it to just remove full duplicate lines, or ones that are a duplicate with the first column only.

Comment: That was part of my comment on his question also:  The OP seems to be asking to remove only one of the sets of lines with the first field identical.

Comment: @RaidPinata, I edited the question, could you check it now?

Comment: I just tested the second bit of code and it takes the output that you have in the first section and produces the output you want in the second section. Can you review my edited answer and see if it solves your question?

Comment: @RaidPinata, I run the code again, the output consists of two lines ; ALIC00AUS_R_20183350000.gz -4052052.7 4212835.9 -2545104.6 and CPVG00CPV_R_20183460000.gz 5626883.4 -2380932.3 1824483.9

Comment: @RaidPinata, I tried awk '!seen[$0]++' filename > outputfile. This time, the output consists of 4 times ALIC00AUS rather than 5 (as indicated the output in the question) which is wrong output.

Comment: @RaidPinata, I only need to remove the last line from each set.

Comment: This doesn't solve the question @deepblue_86 is asking. However, it does solve the problem that other readers might think is being asked. Should I leave the answer for that reason or delete it because it isn't an actual solution?